# Timber Image - using custom sizes

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

Posting this here before I make an issue on https://github.com/timber/timber/

I want to display an ACF image with a custom size like:

```
<img src="{{ image.sizes.medium }}" width="{{ image.sizes.medium-width }}" height="{{ image.sizes.medium-height }}" alt="{{ image.alt }}" title="{{ image.title }}">
```

Here's the `image` array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 473
    ...
    [width] => 768
    [height] => 400
    [sizes] => Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => http://assets.url.com/uploads/image-150x150.jpg
        [thumbnail-width] => 150
        [thumbnail-height] => 150
        [medium] => http://assets.url.com/uploads/image-300x300.jpg
        [medium-width] => 300
        [medium-height] => 300
        [medium_large] => http://assets.url.com/uploads/image-768x400.jpg
        [medium_large-width] => 768
        [medium_large-height] => 400
    ...
    )
)
```

But of course the dash is going to break things so I cannot. Is there a more correct way to do this or should I post this as an issue in github? Or maybe this is an ACF issue? Any help is appreciated that may point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an array in Twig, using the dot notation is only one way to access its contents. You can also access the contents [through the so-called subscript notation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) that works the same as when you’d do it in PHP:

```
<img src="{{ image.sizes.medium }}"
    width="{{ image.sizes['medium-width'] }}"
    height="{{ image.sizes['medium-height'] }}"
    alt="{{ image.alt }}" title="{{ image.title }}">
```

This works only on arrays. If you have dashes in the property name of an **object**, then you’d have to use `attribute()`. Here’s the example from the Twig Documentation:

```
{{ attribute(foo, 'data-foo') }}
```